# Map TouchOverlay and ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a MapView that has an `ItemizedOverlay` on it which displays markers.  This overlay also overrides `onTap` to perform an action when the marker is tapped.

My map also includes a normal `Overlay` that overrides `onTouchEvent` to perform an action when anywhere else on the map is touched.

However, when the user taps on the marker, the `onTouchEvent` from the normal `Overlay` is called as well as the `onTap` from the `ItemizedOverlay`.

So my question is: is there any way to have the `onTouchEvent` not called (or ignored) when the marker is tapped?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an extremely simple solution to this. The answer stems from the way Java inheritance works. Basically, ItemizedOverlay extends Overlay, so all you need to do is to not call the super.onTap() method in your itemizedOverlay override of onTap(). That should do it as far as I know. Do let me know if it doesn't work and I'll provide you with an alternative solution.

Comment: I'm already not calling super.onTap().  Since I have two separate Overlays, I'm not sure how that would work anyways.  However, you did make me realize I can just merge this into one overlay with onTouch and onTap in the same overlay.  However, onTouch is still called when onTap is called.

Comment: Btw, for what purpose are you using both an ItemizedOverlay and Overlays? I can't really think of a use case where you'd need to use both?

Comment: The ItemizedOverlay is what displays the marker.  I am using the normal Overlay to detect when user taps the map so I can load new markers in the tapped location (and remove the old ones).

Comment: Well, if you are using the normal Overlay to detect when the user taps the map. I don't know why you'd do this, just override the MapView class and use a GestureDetector on the map to detect taps on the map, here's the code for the custom MapView and the interface for the custom listener www.pastebin.com/kUrm9zFg at least that's what I do for my app and it works perfectly fine, if you use the code in the link then you can just use something like this: mapView.setOnSingleTapListner(new OnSingleTap Listener() { @Override
public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent arg1) { //// }

Comment: And in that method you could create just create a new ItemizedOverlay for that geopoint (obtainable from the MotionEvent and using map.getProjection() . Thereby eliminating the need to use Overlays, just use ItemizedOverlays and display the marker, and use the custom map click listener to detect a tap on the map and create a point. Trust me, this works, I have an app in production and this code works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks!! I think I'm just going about the tapping on the map portion the wrong way.  Your suggestion sounds like it should work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

make the `ItemizedOverlay` above `Overlay` and let your `onTap` return false.

Comment: How do you make sure one overlay is above the other? Do I just add Overlay first, then ItemizedOverlay? If so, I'm doing that as well as returning false in onTap for the ItemizedOverlay...still no luck